# How to implement remember me ionic framework?

Tags: angular

I have tried to implement remember me using angular js  local storage concept . I can able to get username & password values inside my controller but i am not able to  save those values when user 1st time logs in . Can you help me to find a way to fix this .

Answer (score 0):

Recently I implement something similar, with [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage)  and [localForage-cordovaSQLiteDriver](https://github.com/thgreasi/localForage-cordovaSQLiteDriver)

Here it goes:

1. First of all I configured the localForage settings inside my *index html*, just like this:

   ```
   localforage.defineDriver(window.cordovaSQLiteDriver)
   .then(function (){
     localforage.config({
       driver: [window.cordovaSQLiteDriver._driver,
         localforage.INDEXEDDB,
         localforage.WEBSQL,
         localforage.LOCALSTORAGE
       ],
       name: 'your_db_name',
       storeName: 'store_name',
       version: 1.0,
       description: 'your_local_storage_description'

     });
   });
   ```

   2. You call `$localForage` in your Controller or Service, personally I thought it's better on a Service, and now you can save the data:

   ```
    angular.module('myModule')
         .service('myService',myService);

      myService.$inject=['$localForage'];

      function myService($localForage){
      $localForage.getItem('key');
      $localForage.setItem('key',value);
    }
   ```

It has worked for me, I hope it's useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . will try it :)

Comment: I have implemented using cookies to store & retrieve user credentials .